# Generic stabiliser of moduli space of vector bundles on a curve

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, algebraic-stacks

Let $C$ be a curve of genus $g >1$. Fix a line bundle $L$ on $C$. Let $Bun_{n,L}$ be the moduli stack of vector bundles of rank $n$ on $C$ with determinant isomorphic to $L$. I have a few questions regarding the generic stabilizer of this stack.

1. Is the generic stabilizer trivial? In other words is this stack an orbifold?
2. If not, then what is the rigidification (denoted $Bun_{n,L}^{R}$) of the stack, in concrete terms. More specifically can we say something about $Bun_{n,L}^{R}(X)$, for a scheme $X$. Assume $X$ here is not an algebraically closed field, as stack and its rigidification have same coarse moduli space.

Any references will be appreciated.

Comment: Every vector bundle has the scalar group $\mathbb{G}_m$ as a subgroup of its automorphism group.  If you include the isomorphism of the determinant with $L$ as part of your datum, that reduces the scalar group to $\mu_n$.

Comment: Right. I did mean isomorphism of determinant $L$. Will make an edit to reflect that. and Thanks. That answers the first part of the question